# Big projects that require very good performance really don't use polymorphism?

Tags: c++, optimization, design-patterns, data-oriented-design

For quite some time I have been interested in perfomance in C ++.

A lot of things keep coming up, whether in conferences or in books:

Do not use a virtual function, have the data in the cache, the branches etc.

There are many benchmarks with examples of video games to show the differences in performance.
The thing is, the examples are always very simple.

How does that really work in code that is more than 20 lines? in AAA video games, finance etc.

If I have 100 types of objects that have different update, different behavior and other joys, it's easy to set up via polymorphism or function pointers.

Now, by following the advice given to make a powerful code, the above options are not possible.
We will therefore prefer to have 100 arrays that we will update separately.
We will have good access to the cache, the functions will probably be inline etc. in short, the performance will in principle be better.

So, I have 100 arrays and 100 differents functions that i will have to call at each frame.
The tables dynamically change depending on what happens, new players appear, a monster dies etc.
Some array will have 0 elements active, others 10...
I would call functions that will have no work (array without active element) but I have no choice, I have to have a flag or look if elements are active or not in my array.

I end up with something like this:

```cpp
obj1update ();
obje2update ();
....

obj1behavior ();
obj2behavior ();
....

obj1render ();
obj2render ();
.....

objectxy ();
....
```

Of course, there will undoubtedly be a function which manages all the update calls on the objects, one for the behavior etc but to simplify it gives as above.

To stay in the video game, if the x action of a player causes the arrival of y monsters, there are several types of monsters which have different functions.
We will therefore put the monsters in our tables and this time the functions dealing with these monsters will have work.

We can use the ECS pattern or a derivative but they will potentially have very different behaviors (an ia that directs them or other), different components and therefore different functions will be needed to process them.
They will be called hard in the code since we don't have polymorphism or function pointers and we will have to check at each frame if they have something to process or not.

Is it really done that way? suppose i have 500 types? 1000 ?

**Edit:**

Lots of comments so I'll get back to you here.

As Federico said, I want to know if these recommendations are good for books but less so in practice.

Several resources that I have looked at:

https://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp
Great suite of several books

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE&t](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE&t)
Scott Meyers talk on memory

[https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Elstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf)
On memory

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc&t](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc&t)
Data-oriented programming

https://www.dataorienteddesign.com/dodbook/
data oriented design book

There are also other resources but it already gives you an idea on what I'm basing

Comment: runtime polymorphism via virtual functions is perhaps one of the most overused and misused features, but when it is the right tool then it is the right tool.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're doing premature optimization here. -- If you're really concerned maybe build a small prototype to try out various options side by side?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I don't think he's doing nothing specifically, it's probably just curious to understand how theory clash with the real world needings.
Probably looking at some open source games or big projects will help you to understand how they handle problems like these.

Comment: Of course if you come up with extreme hypothetical scenarios like a thousand types, things will start to break down..

Comment: @Federico: I wasn't there but I think the recommendations that the OP quotes, `Do not use a virtual function, have the data in the cache, the branches etc.`, were meant by those who gave them to be applied where it makes sense, that is where there's a measurable issue with performance. Else you could just say "write everything in assembler" since that's always potentially the fastest, and no one would actually do that.

Comment: problem is cache miss. To run virtual method v-table has to be reached and this is different area of memory what leads to cache miss. In general it is not problem, but if you have tight loop which invokes virtual functions this cache miss issue can be quite significant. If you known list of types at compile time you can keep them in separate containers and this way avoid cache misses. There is nice cppcon  talk explaining this in details (now can't find link to it).

Comment: @antho polymorphism is kept to high-level functionality when performance is important. One doesn't use polymorphism to replace a plus operation. In case of AAA games, you should note that most creatures are modifiable in an editor - so they are classified in a much smaller subset of classes. And usually the graphics are the bottleneck in performance.

Comment: @ALX23z They still have to call functions, right?

Comment: I started writing an answer but I found this question was too broad, encompassing too many different questions. Is your main confusion about the polymorphism?

Comment: I think your main confusion can be answered with one comment: `switch(monsters[i].type) {case BAT: ...; case MUMMY: ...; case VAMPIRE: ...;}`

Comment: and different monsters have more things in common than you think

Comment: Yes it is a radical solution ^^

I would just like to know if the advice given in all the performance books / talks is really applied in real code.

@Marek R, if you find the link, I am interested in having it

Comment: Recommendations for books are off-topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: @antho calling a regular function is faster than a virtual one and furthermore regular function calls can be inlined eliminating the call overhead. Which is why in high performance cases they like to accept lambdas for accessing instead of `std::function` or similar things.

Comment: @user253751 Yes but in varying gameplay, they don't all attack the same way, you have to code somewhere your behavior and without polymorphism or function pointer, you will need multiple arrays.
I'm not asking for book recommendations .. I just give sources and ask if all of these principles are really applied.
Moreover 70% were found on stackoverflow

Comment: @antho I'm not sure this is the correct link (I would have to watch whole thing), but this is my best guess: https://youtu.be/yy8jQgmhbAU

Comment: @Marek R thank you, I have already seen this talk but it is an example that is difficult to visualize on a real code.
With polymorphism it is possible to have several types of animations in 1 array.
In its code, there are templates everywhere. So either we only use 1 animation type or we need 1 array per animation type and we come back to my question.

Comment: @ALX23z so they have x arrays and at each frame they have to look at the array or a flag to know whether or not they should call the function.

Comment: @antho I find it very strange that you say it's impossible to do this without polymorphism or function pointer or multiple arrays, because I can think of one way which I already mentioned: `switch(type) {case BAT: doBatAttack(); break; case MUMMY: doMummyAttack(); break; case VAMPIRE: doVampireAttack(); break;}`

Comment: @antho - it is a lot more complicated than that. Some are indeed processed this way - 500 monsters and each tick process each monster, even if it is 1000 operations it results in 0.5m operations which is a small portion of what a single processor core is capable of during a single tick. But frequrntly operations are simply processed by schedulers via a subscription/notification system. Only a relatively few non-graphic properties require tick by tick check ups. There are location based checks but those are again processed differently.

Comment: @ALX23z So a system based on function pointers or something like that.

This is what seems logical to me to do but it is the kind of thing that is not recommended because of branches etc.
(Not recommended in a system requiring performance)

But I think I understood better

Comment: Here are some related subjects: [Data-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-oriented_design) and [data-locality optimizations](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html#sample-code). These things are massively used in well-optimized recent AAA games. In HPC applications (as for few AAA game studios), advanced object-oriented features are generally simply banished (typically polymorphism and virtuality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, real programs are not written like that. Real programs are written by noticing that all the monsters have a bunch of things *in common*, and using the same code to do those things. They all pathfind, but they have different distances they can walk? Great. Add a `max_walking_distance` variable and call the same function each time.

All your monsters have a 3D model? Then you don't need a virtual `render` method. You can just render the model.

You don't have to divide up your data according to "sensible" boundaries. You don't *have to* have a `struct monster`. You can have a `struct monster_pathfinding` and a `struct monster_position` and a `struct monster_3d_model`. Even if you just put these in parallel arrays (i.e. monster 123 has its pathfinding info in `monsters_pathfinding[123]` and its position in `monster_positions[123]`) this can make more efficient use of the data cache, because the pathfinding code doesn't load the 3D model pointers into the cache. You can get cleverer by skipping entries if some monsters *don't* pathfind or *don't* render. Essentially it is recommended for performance that you group data together according to how it's used, not according to your mental model of the things in the game. Yes, skipping entries makes it way more difficult to delete monsters. But you tick monsters a lot, and you don't delete monsters very often, right?

Maybe only a few monsters shoot guns at the player (the rest try to eat the player). You can have a `struct monster_gun_data {int ammunition; int max_ammunition; int reload_time; monster_position *position;};` and then if you have 200 monsters, but only 10 of them have guns, your `monstersShootGunsAtPlayers` function only has to iterate over the 10 entries in the `monster_gun_data` array (and load their positions via pointers). Or, you might profile that and find out that because *most* monsters in your game have guns, it's slightly faster to iterate over *all* the monsters and check their `MONSTER_HAS_GUN` flag instead, than to access the position through a pointer which can't be prefetched as easily.

How do you do different kinds of monster attacks? Well, if they're *completely* different (melee vs ranged), you probably do them with different functions as you have described. Or you might only check the attack type after you decide the monster wants to attack the player. You seem to suggest monsters use different attack code, but I bet this works for almost all of them:

```
if(wantsToAttack(monster, player)) {
    if((monster->flags & HAS_RANGED_ATTACK) && distance(monster, player) > monster->melee_attack_distance)
        startRangedAttack(monster, player);
    else
        startMeleeAttack(monster, player);
}
```

And what's *really* different between a monster with a gun, and a monster with a bow and arrow? The attack speed, the animation, the speed the projectile moves at, the projectile's 3D model, and the amount of damage it does. That's all data. That isn't different code.

Finally, if you have something *completely* different, you might consider making it a "strategy object" with a virtual function. Or just a plain function pointer, if you can. Note that the `Monster` object is still not polymorphic, because if it was, we couldn't have an array of them and that would slow down all the common code. Only the specific parts of the monster that we're saying are polymorphic are actually polymorphic.

```
void SpecialBossTickFunction(Monster *monster) {
    // special movement, etc
}
// ...
monster->onTick = &SpecialBossTickFunction;
// monster is still not polymorphic except for this one field
```

You could also do:

```
struct SpecialBossTickStrategy : TickStrategy {
    void onTick(Monster *monster) override {...}
    // then you can also have extra fields if needed
    // but you also have more indirection
};
monster->onTick = new SpecialBossTickStrategy;
```

And don't do stuff unnecessarily. Try to be event-driven instead of doing stuff every tick:

```
// bad because we're calling this function unnecessarily every tick
void SpecialUndeadMonsterTickFunction(Monster *monster) {
    if(monster->isDead) {
        // do some special reanimation sequence
    }
}
monster->onTick = &SpecialUndeadMonsterTickFunction;

// better (for performance)
void SpecialUndeadMonsterTickWhileDeadFunction(Monster *monster) {
    // do some special reanimation sequence
    if (finished doing whatever) {
        monster->onTick = NULL;
    }
}
void SpecialUndeadMonsterDeathFunction(Monster *monster) {
    monster->onTick = &SpecialUndeadMonsterTickWhileDeadFunction;
}
// ...
monster->onDead = &SpecialUndeadMonsterDeathFunction;

// Also better (for performance)
void DoUndeadMonsterReanimationSequences() { // not virtual at all, called from the main loop
    for(Monster *monster : special_undead_monsters_which_are_currently_dead) {
        // do some special reanimation sequence
    }
}

// Not great, but perhaps still less bad than the first one!
void DoUndeadMonsterReanimationSequences() { // not virtual at all, called from the main loop
    for(Monster &monster : all_monsters) {
        if(monster.type == TYPE_SPECIAL_UNDEAD_MONSTER && monster.isDead) {
            // do some special reanimation sequence
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the third example you have to keep this array `special_undead_monsters_which_are_currently_dead` up to date. That's okay, because you only have to change it when a monster spawns, disappears, dies, or un-dies. And those are relatively rare events. You are doing a bit more work in these events, in order to save work every tick.

---

Finally, keep in mind these are techniques that may or may not improve performance in your actual program. I see DOD as a grab-bag of ideas. *It doesn't say you must write your program in exactly a certain way,* but it is offering a bunch of unconventional suggestions, the theory to explain why they work, and examples of how other people have managed to use them in their programs. Since DOD usually suggests that you complete reorganize your data structures, you may only want to implement it in the performance-critical areas of your program.

Comment: Thanks, there are some things that I understand better.

To be sure, the 4th function is therefore called at each frame, if the array is empty it returns directly, otherwise it processes the elements but there is indeed the check I was talking about

Comment: @antho it's not clear to me which one is the 4th function

Comment: 7th function sorry

Comment: they have names, maybe you can use the name

Comment: first void DoUndeadMonsterReanimationSequences();

Comment: I should have said most real programs do use virtual functions, but if you want to avoid virtual functions then this is how you do it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some more perspective on the top-level question:

> Big projects that require very good performance really don't use polymorphism?

You're missing out an entire category of polymorphism.

I often mix all three of the below styles in a project, because not all code has the same performance requirements:

1. setup and configuration code doesn't generally need to be (very) fast. Use OO style and *runtime* polymorphism all you want for properties, factories, whatever.

   Runtime polymorphism broadly means virtual functions.
2. steady-state code that *does* need to be fast can often use *compile-time* polymorphism. This works well for a statically-known (and ideally small) collection of types with similar interfaces.

   Compile-time polymorphism means templates (function templates, type templates, replacing the run-time Strategy pattern with the equivalent Policy, etc.)
3. the code with the tightest performance requirements may need to be data-oriented (ie, designed around cache friendliness).

   This isn't *all* the code in the project, and probably isn't even all the code that needs to be fast. It's all the code that needs to be fast and *where performance is dominated by cache effects*.

   If you only have one copy of an object, you may well inline as much as possible (and try to fit it into the fewest cache lines possible), but splitting it into four different arrays with only one element each won't achieve much.